# struct in header file

Tags: c, struct

I want have two shared structs.

In my .h:

```
typedef struct {
  char nombre[25];
  int pv;
  char ataque1[25];
  char ataque2[25];
  char ataque3[25];
  char ataque4[25];
  char ataque1_estado[25];
  char ataque2_estado[25];
  char ataque3_estado[25];
  char ataque4_estado[25];
  char estado[25];
  int pd_max[4];
  int pd_min[4];
  int pp[4];
  int pociones;
  int antidotos;
} pokemon;

extern pokemon pokemon1;
extern pokemon pokemon2;
```

And in my .c files:

```
#include "file.h"
//file body, i use here structs in file.h
```

But it doesn't compile. GCC shows this error:

> main.c:(.text+0x440): referencia a `pokemon1' sin definir

What is wrong?

Comment: @atturri Yes, but i want use the same structures in both .c files, sharing the structures info.

Comment: Yes, you will, don't worry. You **must** define the objects in a unique .c file, but thanks to the `extern` in the .h file the other .c files will be using the same objects.

Comment: @atturri Thanks a lot! i understand and compile very well :)

Answer (score 3):

The last two lines in your header file are the **declaration** of your `pokemon` objects, which allow you to use them from multiple .c files. But in one of the .c files you must **define** them, which in your case is the same as declaring but without the `extern` keyword:

```
pokemon pokemon1;
pokemon pokemon2;
```